# Page Break for Each Parameter Chosen

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with two tables and a graph. These items are determined by a parameter selected before loading the report (multiple items can be selected). I'd like to have it so that a page break is inserted following each table/graph for that selected parameter. Is it possible to specify this separation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is , 
Insert everything in one list, Filter list  on your parameter and in row group properties use option page break "between each instance of the group". this should work...

Comment: This could be what I'm looking for. However, when I insert my existing table into the list (which creates a Tablix with a Rectangle within...), I get the following message when trying to run: `The tablix ‘Tablix8’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.`

Comment: Manually adding a table, where do you find the "page break between each instance of the group" property? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ok , you need to double click on row group property ( on the bottom of the page - you got two windows one for row goups and one for column groups ) - If you cant see it you have to enable "Group Windows" option.

Comment: Yep I found the option for that. How do I add a table in though? It complains about a detail member when I add a table to a list.